# Why isn't css rendered with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to add html dynamically through a jquery function. Basically I have a DIV with an ID and I try to append some html code to the DIV. It seems like the css isn't being rendered. I have also tried to set a timeout so that the css has time to load, but that didn't help. If I put the html directly into the DIV it works fine. Any guidance on what the problem might be is highly appreciated. Here is my code:

CSS call:

```
  <head>
 <!-- Theme style -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css"  media="all">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css"  
  media="all">

 </head>
```

HTML:

```
<section>
<div class="row" id="seating_view" > </div>
</section>
```

jQuery:

```
function getSeatings()
{
 console.log("function get seatings @start");     
 $('#seating_view').append('<div class="row" >',                 
    '<div  class="col-md-6">',
     '<div class="box" id="trialbox2">',
       '<div class="box-header with-border">',
        '<h3 class="box-title email"id ="trial-header2">Berammede rettssaker kunder</h3>',
         '<div class="box-tools pull-right">',
            '<button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i>',
            '</button>',            
            '<button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>',
            '</div>',
          '</div>',
          '<div class="box-body">',
            '<div class="row">',
             '<div class="col-md-12">',             
              '<div class="table-responsive" >',
              '<div style="display:block-inline; height:185px; max-height:185px;  overflow-y:auto;">',
              '<table class="table no-margin"  style=" overflow-y:auto " >',
              '<thead style="display:block-inline;" >',
              '<tr>',
                '<th>Selskap</th>',                    
                '<th>Avholdes</th>',                 
                '<th>Saken gjelder</th>',                   
                '<th>Lenke</th>',
              '</tr>',
              '</thead>',   
              '<tbody id =""></tbody>',
             '</table>',
              '</div>',
            '</div>',
           '</div>',
          '</div>',
         '</div>',
        '</div>',
       '</div>',
      '</div>'); 

 };
```

Comment: I've not used the multiple argument form of append before, but I suspect every argument has to be an HTML string (if using strings like this), which means you can't split the opening and closing tags into separate strings, as that makes both of them invalid HTML. After this runs, do you see the expected structure in your browser dev tools?

Comment: @objelland Can you please check in browser network panel whether CSS file is loading or not?

Comment: Yes, the css loads when I check the browser dev tool

Comment: @SpoonMeiser; The structure is actually only showing one of the closing DIVs, teh other </div> elements are not there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using template literals

```js
function getSeatings() {
  $('#seating_view').append(`<div class="row" >              
    <div  class="col-md-6">
      <div class="box" id="trialbox2">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
          <h3 class="box-title email"id ="trial-header2">Berammede rettssaker kunder</h3>
          <div class="box-tools pull-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse">
              <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
            </button>         
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove">
              <i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="box-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">         
                <div class="table-responsive">
                  <div style="display:block-inline; height:185px; max-height:185px; overflow-y:auto;">
                    <table class="table no-margin" style="overflow-y:auto">
                      <thead style="display:block-inline;">
                        <tr>
                          <th>Selskap</th>
                          <th>Avholdes</th>                 
                          <th>Saken gjelder</th>               
                          <th>Lenke</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody></tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>`);
 };
```

This is ES6 template literal

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution to the solution. I had to handle the HTML code as one string only. When the HTML is enclosed with " " it works fine.

Comment: @objelland Did you mean you got a solution to the problem?